# Export ASN.1 format, then encode with Base64 JAVA

Tags: java, encoding, bouncycastle, asn.1

I want to make a custom ASN.1 structure, what consists of 3 `PrintableString`'s and 1 `OctetString`. I am using BouncyCastle framework to work with this.

So I set in my class the needed parameters, and now I have to return this structure in ASN.1 format, and then encode it with Base64 (its parameter is byte[]), then into PEM format.

So my question is, that what type of object do I have to return from method `getASN1format()`?

My code:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ASN1Handshake1 implements ASN1Encodable {
    private DERPrintableString A, B, ID_PASS;
    private ASN1OctetString ID_K;

    public ASN1Handshake1(String A, String B, String ID_K, String ID_PASS, TTP TTPs ) throws IOException {
        this.A = new DERPrintableString(A);
        this.B = new DERPrintableString(B);
        this.ID_K = new DEROctetString(ID_K.getBytes());
        this.ID_PASS = new DERPrintableString(ID_PASS);
    }

    public ?? getASN1format(){
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public ASN1Primitive toASN1Primitive() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using **Bouncy Castle 1.57** (bcprov-jdk15on) for this code.

First of all, keep in mind that ASN.1 is not a format *per se*, it's a [description language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) that **defines** a structure, and [PEM is a format that **uses** base 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-enhanced_Electronic_Mail). Many cryptography standards use ASN.1 to define their data structures, and PEM or [DER (Distinguished Encoding Rules)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) to serialize those structures.

So, if you want to get the ASN.1 structure and format it to base64, you can do as below. You don't need a `getASN1format` method, just use the existent ones.

The fields can't just be "loose" in the ASN.1 structure. So I decided to put them in a sequence (using `org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERSequence` class), which is the best choice to store fields of a structure. I put them in the order they're declared, but of course you can choose any order you want.

I've also changed the variables names to follow [Java's code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#15429) (names start with lowercase letters). So the class code is:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Encodable;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Object;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OctetString;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROctetString;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERPrintableString;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERSequence;

public class ASN1Handshake1 extends ASN1Object {

    private DERPrintableString a, b, idPass;

    private ASN1OctetString idK;

    // removed TTPs parameter (it wasn't using it)
    public ASN1Handshake1(String a, String b, String idK, String idPass) {
        this.a = new DERPrintableString(a);
        this.b = new DERPrintableString(b);
        this.idK = new DEROctetString(idK.getBytes());
        this.idPass = new DERPrintableString(idPass);
    }

    // returns a DERSequence containing all the fields
    @Override
    public ASN1Primitive toASN1Primitive() {
        ASN1Encodable[] v = new ASN1Encodable[] { this.a, this.b, this.idK, this.idPass };
        return new DERSequence(v);
    }
}
```

To create a handshake object and convert it to base64 (the code below is not handling exceptions, so add the `try/catch` block accordingly):

```
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

// create handshake object with some sample data
ASN1Handshake1 handshake = new ASN1Handshake1("a", "b", "ID_K", "ID_PASS");

// convert it to base64
String base64String = new String(Base64.encode(handshake.getEncoded()));
System.out.println(base64String);
```

This will output the handshake structure in base64 format:

> MBUTAWETAWIEBElEX0sTB0lEX1BBU1M=

Please note that this is not a complete PEM (with headers like `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`) because your custom structure is not a predefined standard. So, you'll have to stay with this base64 generic string.

To check that the base64 string contains the ASN.1 sequence, just do:

```
// read from base64 String
ASN1Sequence seq = (ASN1Sequence) DERSequence.fromByteArray(Base64.decode(base64String.getBytes()));
int n = seq.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ASN1Encodable obj = seq.getObjectAt(i);
    if (obj instanceof DEROctetString) {
        System.out.println(new String(((DEROctetString) obj).getOctets()));
    } else {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

The output is:

> a
>   b
>   ID_K
>   ID_PASS

Comment: Thank you Hugo, more than satisfying answer.

Comment: Your example doesn't show it, but in general PEM is base64 _with added linebreaks every 64 (or so) characters_ plus dashed-BEGIN/END-typename lines.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The BEGIN/END are for defined types, like certificate, CSR, keys and so on. But in this case it's a custom structure with a "non-standard" format. I'm not sure if one can just create a new type or if it's standardized.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 With PEM format I did not have problem, so I did write it in the question. It was for school project, and we got custom types of which we had to put into first and last line depending on message type.